# Comment out items that do not match pattern in array

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, terminal

I have a log file I am trying to comment out lines that do not match my array.  I did successfully learn how to create an array and I can echo out the array items but I am having trouble taking anything that doesn't match my array and adding something in front of it.  Here is my code, if you have suggestions on another path or ways I can make it better:

```
for itsSaturday in $(find "$LOCATION" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*.log" ); do
    TEMPFILE="$itsSaturday.$$"
    declare -a someArray=( "breakfast" "scrambled eggs" "Bloody Mary" )
    theCall='some_additional_text_'
    commentOn="## You_need_"
    for arrayItem in "${someArray[@]}"; do
        merged="$theCall$arrayItem"
        if ! grep -q "$merged" "$itsSaturday"; then 
            sed -e '/$merged/! s:$commentOn$theCall::g' "$itsSaturday" > $TEMPFILE && mv $TEMPFILE "$itsSaturday"
        fi      
    done
done
```

file:

```
some_additional_text_breakfast
some_additional_text_bacon
some_additional_text_scrambled eggs
some_additional_text_Bloody Mary
some_additional_text_orange juice
some_additional_text_breakfast
```

file into:

```
some_additional_text_breakfast
## You_need_some_additional_text_bacon
some_additional_text_scrambled eggs
some_additional_text_Bloody Mary
## You_need_some_additional_text_orange juice
some_additional_text_breakfast
```

How can I add a variable before items that do not match my array?

Comment: why the downvote??  Just curious for the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like doing this using `bash` and `sed`, but I think the following might be enough:

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -a someArray=( "breakfast" "scrambled eggs" "Bloody Mary" )
theCall='some_additional_text_'
commentOn="## You_need_"

OIFS="$IFS"
IFS='|' mergedLines="${someArray[*]/#/$theCall}"
IFS="$OIFS"

for i in *.txt
do
    TEMPFILE="$i.$$"
    sed -r "/$mergedLines/!s/^/$commentOn/" "$i" >> "$TEMPFILE"
done
```

1. I shifted the array and other constants out of the loop.
2. `"${someArray[*]/#/$theCall}"` uses bash string substitution to append the contents of `$theCall` to every element in the array.
3. `IFS='|' mergedLines="${someArray[*]}` is a convenient trick to combine the elements of an array into a pipe-separated string.
4. Combined, (2) and (3) get me

   ```
   some_additional_text_breakfast|some_additional_text_scrambled eggs|some_additional_text_Bloody Mary
   ```

   in `mergedLines`.
5. Then it's just a matter of using extended regular expressions in `sed`  (for `|`) and replacing non-matching lines.
6. Your `sed` pattern used single quotes, so the variables within were not expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the inner for-loop with:

```
PROG=$(printf '%s\n' "${COMMENT[@]}" | while read comment ; do
  /bin/echo -n '$0 !~ /'"$comment"'$/ && '
done
echo '1 { printf commentOn } ; { print }')
awk -v commentOn="$commentOn" "$PROG" $itsSaturday > $TEMPFILE && mv $TEMPFILE $itsSaturday
```

On each file, this creates an awk program that does the work.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but Im getting an error: `find: ftsopen: No such file or directory`

Comment: You sure you're using bash?  Do you have #!/bin/bash at the top?  If so, try replacing "awk" with "nawk" or "gawk".